# Checking if an item in a list is in another list

Tags: python, list

```
values = ['Limpets', 'Mussels', 'Phytoplankton', 'Zooplankton', 'Prawn', 'Crab', 'Whelk', 'Seaweed']

keys = ['Whelk ', 'Mussels ', 'Bird ', 'Prawn ', 'Fish ', 'Zooplankton ', 'Crab ', 'Lobster ', 'Limpets ']
```

What I want is the items in values that are not in keys. I have tried writing it as:

```
for item in values:
   if item not in keys:
       print(item)
```

the answer is should get is

```
phytoplankton
seaweed
```

but what i get instead is:

```
Phytoplankton
Seaweed
Limpets
Mussels
Crab
Whelk
Prawn
Zooplankton
```

I also tried storing the item in a list and then printing that list but nothing I've tried is working for me. I saw some answers using list comprehension but I'm taking an introductory course so all I've got is loops... I'm using python3.5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: It would help a lot to include what results you're expecting and what results you're getting, so that we can get a better idea of what your expectations are. However, I notice that each string in the `keys` list has a trailing space, which is almost certainly screwing up your comparison....

Comment: @thefourtheye it prints all of the list, values

Comment: As some of the answers below suggest your keys have trailing spaces so you need to account for that

Comment: You need `map(lambda x : x.strip(),keys)`  since there are spaces in keys

Comment: @PraiseOkwa, such a good question, no one ever upvote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The thing is, each string in your **keys** list contains a space at the end. This code:

```
values = ['Limpets', 'Mussels', 'Phytoplankton', 'Zooplankton', 'Prawn', 'Crab', 'Whelk', 'Seaweed']

keys = ['Whelk', 'Mussels', 'Bird', 'Prawn', 'Fish', 'Zooplankton', 'Crab', 'Lobster', 'Limpets']

for item in values:
   if item not in keys:
       print(item)
```

produces this output:

*Phytoplankton
Seaweed*

If for some reason you cannot modify the entires of **keys**, you can modify your loops to be:

```
for item in values:
   if item + " " not in keys:
       print(item)
```

which will give you the same output:

*Phytoplankton
Seaweed*

Comment: Thanks this worked great for me. I couldn't modify the entires of keys, so i think my problem was modifying the loops.

Answer (score 5):

Just use sets

```
set(values).difference(set(keys))
```

Or for this particular example OP can use

```
set(values).difference(set([i.strip() for i in keys]))
```

Since the `keys` list has a trailing space for each item so we need to clear that up.

Comment: This may not maintain the order of elements. #justsaying

Comment: #truethat , if order is not important then this approach is fine.

Comment: It`s not a matter of the coolest/best way to obtain the difference between the lists. Otherwise his code would have worked.

Comment: Realised the space part later kind sir. Nevertheless I hope the OP got introduced to the power of `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

in keys list you have spaces after words for example 'Whelk ', but in values you don't f.e 'Whelk'. 'Whelk ' and  'Whelk' are two different words so when you write

```py
if item not in keys:
```

it returns true. you should remove whitespace after words in keys list first and then try your code sample

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
[x for x in values if x not in keys]
```

Comment: You need `not x in keys`. Also - it might make sense to convert `keys` to a set.

Comment: It`s not a matter of the coolest/best way to obtain the difference between the lists. Otherwise his code would have worked

Answer (score 1):

as per you question below will help

```
[i for i in keys if i.strip() not in values]
```

Also, you can use `set` in python for more evaluations of this kind

Answer (score 1):

It will return the whole list because your keys contains additional spaces in each string so you have to remove the spaces first.

```
updated_keys = [i.strip() for i in keys]

answer_list = [i for i in values if i not in updated_keys]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list(set(values) - set([i.strip() for i in keys]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to use `map(lambda x : x.strip(),keys)` then use reduce or any other solution

```
values = ['Limpets', 'Mussels', 'Phytoplankton', 'Zooplankton', 'Prawn', 'Crab', 'Whelk', 'Seaweed']
keys = ['Whelk ', 'Mussels ', 'Bird ', 'Prawn ', 'Fish ', 'Zooplankton ', 'Crab ', 'Lobster ', 'Limpets ']
map(lambda x : x.strip(),keys)
reduce(lambda x , y : x+ [y] if y.strip() not in keys else x, values,[])
```

O/P : `['Phytoplankton', 'Seaweed']`

Comment: The OP uses python 3.5 and `reduce` is deprecated. In any case,  lambdas are expensive and unnecessary here.

Comment: @Pynchia where is it mentioned it uses python 3.5

Comment: @Pynchia You could still get reduce from `from functools import reduce` . Why are lambdas expensive. Isn't set operation too a bit expensive. Would like to learn if you can show it is expensive.